# Angular breaks when I access page directly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular project that has some parts (specifically the top nav) broken when pages are accessed directly/reloaded. The rest of the page works fine. Only topnav having things like `ui-sref` not expanding to `href` and data not loading. I also noticed the topnav controller is not run at all when I reload/access the page directly.

In the `ui-router` config there is this `app` abstract route

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: helper.basepath('app.html'),
    resolve: helper.resolveFor('fastclick', 'modernizr', 'icons', 'screenfull', 'animo', 'sparklines', 'slimscroll', 'classyloader', 'toaster', 'whirl', 'spinkit', 'akoenig.deckgrid')
  })
```

It probably came with the theme the project is using. Anyways, in the app.html file

```
<!-- top navbar-->
<header ng-include="'app/views/partials/top-navbar.html'" class="topnavbar-wrapper"></header>
```

Then in `top-navbar.html`

```
{{'OUTSIDE'}}
<nav ng-controller="TopNavBarController" role="navigation" class="navbar topnavbar" style="background-color:#1663DE;">
  {{'INSIDE'}}
```

The outside and inside are for debugging. I noticed on reload or when page is accessed directly, angular prints the `OUTSIDE` correctly in HTML but fails to print inside correctly. It appears on page as `{{'INSIDE'}}`. Which makes me think there is something wrong with the `ng-controller`. Removing `ng-controller` fixes this particular problem.

I added a `log` right after the controller function:

```
function TopNavBarController($scope, $state, SweetAlert) {
  console.log('in TopNavBarController')
```

It appears the controller function is not even run? Whats wrong?

Only topbar is failing, the rest of the controller/application works fine. Data can be loaded, `ui-sref` expanding correctly.

Comment: I assume ur r not using hashbang urls?

Comment: @StenMuchow, this project is. Does it matter? You mean URLs like `localhost/#/app/home` correct?

Comment: From what I understand of your problem use it seemed to be a deeplinking error. I seem to be mistaken, if u can duplicate your problem in a PLUNKR or similar I can try better to help.

Comment: Didn't answer if using hashed url or html5mode? Sounds like you are using html5mode and don't have absolute paths set right for resources. Check requests made in browser dev tools network as well as errors thrown in console

Comment: @charlietfl I am using hashed URLs like `#/app/home`. And one of the problem is no errors in console ...

Comment: No errors when you keep `ng-controller`? When angular doesn't compile `{{}}` is almost always due to errors thrown unless there is any dom code outside angular context  inserting that html

Comment: @charlietfl, yes I am confused too ... angular fails to compile but I see no errors ... wonder if this theme is swallowing errors ...